# what is the reson for this wso2 analytics dashboard (3.2.0) error

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I run both API manager and analytics locally .can anyone help me pls with this error on analytics dashboard ?

```
 [2021-11-22 08:28:14,461]  WARN {org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JHttpConnectorListener} - Error 
 in http connector listener : 'Remote client closed the connection before initiating outbound 
 response'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not an error and I just used pizza shack to publish statics .so you need to publish another API like openweatherapi and also subscribe and it was my problem.